# How to stop OnTouch method after one touche

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, osmdroid

i have one small problem.Basically what i want to do is draw waypoint to map ,with touches.But i want to stop that onTouch method after one waypoint added,cause now it add more waypoints with one click ,and continue add them with next touches.

Heres the method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        final MapPoint point=(MapPoint) data.getSerializableExtra("result");
         GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51496994, -134254);
         point.setGeo(point2);



                    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                            GeoPoint geo = null;
                            IProjection project = view.getProjection();
                            geo=(GeoPoint)project.fromPixels((int)e.getX(),(int)e.getY());
                            mainDrawer.addGeopointToMap(point.getName(), point.getDesc(), geo);
                            return false;
                        }});
    }
```

Comment: take a look at action (down, up ...) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply set the actionListener to **null**
this will make the action to called at the first time, then it will be null so it will not called again.

```
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                        GeoPoint geo = null;
                        IProjection project = view.getProjection();
                        geo=(GeoPoint)project.fromPixels((int)e.getX(),(int)e.getY());
                        mainDrawer.addGeopointToMap(point.getName(), point.getDesc(), geo);
                        view.setOnTouchListener(null)
                        return false;
                    }});
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean flag:

```
boolean added = false;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        final MapPoint point=(MapPoint) data.getSerializableExtra("result");
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51496994, -134254);
        point.setGeo(point2);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                if(!added) {
                    GeoPoint geo = null;
                    IProjection project = view.getProjection();
                    geo=(GeoPoint)project.fromPixels((int)e.getX(),(int)e.getY());
                    mainDrawer.addGeopointToMap(point.getName(), point.getDesc(), geo);
                    added = true;
                 }
                 return false;
            }});
}
```

Comment: @JánSrniček Please accept the solution if it answered your query